# sparql datetime subtraction or timezone conversion

Tags: date, datetime, sparql

I'm trying to write a sparql query to subtract a certain number of hours (or convert zulu time to another time zone).

How would I do this?

I currently have something like this:

```
SELECT ?createdDate
WHERE {  
    ?id a ?doc   
    ?id ?p ?date .
BIND (?date as ?createdDate)   
}
```

I think I would do some math in the bind clause to manipulate the date object? The date object currently is of xsd:dateTime format in Zulu time.

Comment: Arthimetic on xsd:dateTime is by using xsd:durations.  Check out the XSD datattype specs and see what your SPARQL engine supports.

Comment: This is not right: ?id xsd:date ?date .  xsd:date is a datatype, not a property.

Comment: sorry...it was meant to be more pseudo code. I've edited now...the actual query I have is a lot larger and was looking for a quick way to represent what im trying to do. I'll check out the xsd:durations - thanks.

Comment: @harmlessdragon It sounds like you're trying to print a particular dateTime in a different timezone, not subtract hours (i.e., get an earlier time) which would produce an _earlier_ time.  Is this correct?  You want the same instant in time, but at a different timezone?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Yes that's correct. I would only want to subtract hours if it's not possible to localize the dateTime.

Comment: @harmlessdragon I think your option might only be what AndyS suggested:  check your implementation's extensions.  The SPARQL 1.1 spec lists the relevant functions, [17.4.5 Functions on Dates and Times](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-date-time), and some [casting operations](http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#FunctionMapping), but I don't think that any of those will let you get a datetime for the same instant, but in a different timezone.  Date calculations can be pretty tricky, so I expect this is something that's easier to let some library in the host language do.

Answer (score 0):

To subtract 1 hour:

```
select ?date ?newDate where {
  ?date a xsd:dateTime .
  bind(?date - xsd:duration('PT1H') as ?newDate) .
}
```

Examples of other durations can be found here: http://www.datypic.com/sc/xsd/t-xsd_duration.html.